# How do I make a list of random unique tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, tuples, unique

I've looked over several answers similar to this question, and all seem to have good oneliner answers that however only deal with the fact of making the list unique by removing duplicates. I need the list to have exactly 5.

The only code I could come up with is as such:

```
from random import *

tuples = []

while len(tuples) < 5:
    rand = (randint(0, 6), randint(0,6))
    if rand not in tuples:
        tuples.append(rand)
```

I feel like there is a simpler way but I can't figure it out. I tried playing with sample() from random:

```
sample((randint(0,6), randint(0,6)), 5)
```

But this gives me a "Sample larger than population or is negative" error.

Comment: Are you looking for just selecting from a small set (e.g. the 49 combinations of `(randint(0, 6), randint(0,6))`) or many possibilities? Do you actually need a `list` (ordered) or is a ``set`` (unordered) fine as well?

Comment: The set is limited, in my program, by a parameter.. so like randint(0, size).
It doesn't have to be ordered.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. By the way, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: Pick five unique numbers.  Then pick five other numbers, not necessarily unique.  Make your tuples by combining one number from the unique list (so all the tuples are also unique) with one number from the other list, working through both lists in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick way is to use `itertools.product` to generate all tuple possibilities before using `sample` to choose 5 from them:

```
from itertools import product
from random import sample
sample(list(product(range(7), repeat=2)), k=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

For such a small set of inputs, just generate all possible outputs, and `sample` them:

```
 import itertools
 import random

 size = 6
 random.sample(list(itertools.product(range(size+1), repeat=2)), 5)
```

You indicate that the bounds (`size`) may be a parameter though, and if the bounds might be even a little larger, this could be a problem (you'd be generating `size ** 2` `tuple`s to select `5` of them, and the memory usage could get out of control). If that's a problem, given you only need a pair of integers, there is a cheap trick: Choose *one* random integer that encodes both resulting integers, then decode it. For example:

```
size = 6
raw_sample = random.sample(range((size + 1) ** 2), 5)
decoded_sample = [divmod(x, size+1) for x in raw_sample)]
```

Since `range` is zero overhead (the memory usage doesn't depend on the length), you can select precisely five values from it with overhead proportionate to the five selected, not the 49 possible results. You then compute the quotient and remainder based on the range of a single value (0 to `size` inclusive in this case, so `size + 1` possible values), and that gets the high and low results cheaply.

The performance differences are stark; comparing:

```
def unique_random_pairs_by_product(size):
    return random.sample(list(itertools.product(range(size+1), repeat=2)), 5)
```

to:

```
def unique_random_pairs_optimized(size):
    val_range = size + 1
    return [divmod(x, val_range) for x in random.sample(range(val_range * val_range), 5)]
```

the `optimized` version takes about 15% less time even for an argument of `6` (~4.65 μs for `product`, ~3.95 μs for `optimized`). But at `size` of `6`, you're not seeing the scaling factor at all. For `size=100`, `optimized` only increases to ~4.35 μs (the time increasing slightly because the larger `range` is more likely to have to allocate new `int`s, instead of using the small `int` cache), while `product` jumps to 387 μs, a nearly 100x difference. And for `size=1000`, the time for `product` jumps to 63.8 ms, while `optimized` remains ~4.35 μs; a factor of 10,000x difference in runtime (and an even higher multiplier on memory usage). If `size` gets any larger than that, the `product`-based solution will quickly reach the point where the delay from even a single sampling is noticeable to humans; the `optimized` solution will continue to run with identical performance (modulo incredibly tiny differences in the cost of the `divmod`).

Comment: Good solution indeed (+1), although if the size is really large, using `sample` can be inherently inefficient, in which case you can consider my other answer as a solution.

Comment: @blhsing: How is it inherently inefficient? The implementation for "huge population, small sample" is pretty similar to what you wrote as it happens; it makes a `set`, and keeps generating new indices and adding them until it has the desired number of unique sample indices, then looking up said unique indices.

Comment: Oops I did not realize that the implementation of `random.sample` for a large `range` object is indeed done with a `while` loop already until I read the source code. Thanks.